# What is the meaning of "Redonkulous"; is it an English Phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, american-english, slang

I want to find out the meaning of an English word called **redonkulous**. Is it a phrase or something? I found this word in an animated movie called ***Bolt***. I searched in "Google" and in "Google Translate" but didn't get any satisfactory answers. So, here I came. If anybody knows, please share it with me. I've added some screen shots of that movie, so that you guys can get some ideas about the conversation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a modification of the word *ridiculous*, using *donk* /dɑŋk/ to replace *dic* /dɪk/:

> Absolutely **ridiculous**!

As you might expect, *redonkulous* sounds a bit silly.  It's considered slang, and only certain people use the altered word.  Although it means "ridiculous", it's non-standard and markedly informal.

I haven't seen the movie in question, but it looks like the bird is repeatedly using the word.  My guess is that it's because *rendonkulous* sounds silly and is supposed to make the audience laugh.

Comment: I imagine the ***donk/dic[k]*** substitution arises from the fact that [both](http://www.slang-dictionary.org/australian-slang/Donk) [words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_(slang)) are slang terms for "penis".

Comment: @Tulon: Bearing in mind *Bolt* is a Disney movie, it's not expected the average viewer will make that connection, but I think it's highly likely the scriptwriters will have sniggered over it. It's not uncommon to find obscure "smutty" references in movies like that. I assume it's to give some *parents* a few extra laughs when they have to sit in at the cinema (or home theatre) watching with their kids. But most of *them* probably won't actually notice this particular one - if it was too obvious the scriptwriters would be told to remove it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I understand. The word is not looking odd or as a slang in the conversation context of the movie. It's been used to make that seen a bit more funny.

Comment: With big budget "family" movies like this (*Bolt* had estimated production costs of [$150,000,000](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397892/)), they often go to considerable trouble to include elements that only register with *some* of the "target" audience, to broaden the potential market appeal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Along those lines, I've also heard *recockulous*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've heard the word used many times (always informally and in a silly context,) but I've never heard it in any way associated with what you say. I think it's just meant to be silly (at least by the majority of its users,) not crude or vulgar.